# Method to accept different types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible for a method to accept any type?

For example can I write:

```
public ActionResult Edit(? vp){

}
```

where `ActionResult` would accept an Integer, float, or any other (possibly custom) type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your meaning so you can use generic like that:

```
public ActionResult Edit<T>(T vp){ }
```

T represent the type you want, and whan you call the method give the type in the <>

or you can use object type like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(object vp){ }
```

hope it helped you!

Comment: And what with what request URL do you intend to invoke this controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `object` and then write a [custom model binder](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx) for it by overriding the [BindModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.bindmodel.aspx) method which will decide what value to returned based on the request.

```
public ActionResult Edit(object vp)
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method can accept an object like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit(object vp)
{
    // you can then cast your object vp to whatever type.
    float x = (float)vp;
}
```

Comment: And what with what request URL do you intend to invoke this controller action?